# Telegram `setTyping` API call

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to set my bot's typing status by sending the following `POST` request (based on the [API docs](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.setTyping)):

`https://api.telegram.org/bot{{botToken}}/setTyping`

```
{
  peer: {{chat_id}},
  typing: true,
  action: 'sendMessageTypingAction'
}
```

I've tried a few variations of it, such as changing the url to be `/messages.setTyping` and sending the action as `{"_":"sendMessageTypingAction"}` [as seen here](https://github.com/pwrtelegram/pwrtelegram/issues/27#issuecomment-286413330), but all I get is:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 404,
    "description": "Not Found: method not found"
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@tashakori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52373242/113721) for pointing me in the right direction towards the Bot API. For posterity, what I needed to do was:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot{{botToken}}/sendChatAction`

```
{
  chat_id: {{chatId}},
  action: 'typing'
}
```

Comment: Great! Haven't noticed that

Answer (score 1):

The link you have mentioned above belongs to Telegram Core APIs which is used for handling ordinary accounts of Telegram. These so-called Core APIs are not related to [Telegram Bot APIs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

The only API that is somehow similar to SetTyping for bots is [AnswerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery), which can be used only when responding to the user's interaction with inline keyboards. (you can send a text to the user, saying that there is a process running in the background and whenever the user's answer is ready, you can send it using APIs like sendMessage)

Comment: Ah, that's not what I needed, but you pointed me in the right direction with the Bot API, thanks!